# How to store values in a 2-D array in column major order in c++?

Tags: c++

I know to store values in an array in row-major order. I'll do it using loops.
But I don't know to store values in column-major order in c++. Please show me the code sample?. I searched the internet, but i didn't find the proper code sample.

Comment: Instead of using e.g. `array[i][j]` use `array[j][i]`?

Comment: Do it with loops, just loop over y in the outer loop instead of x.

Comment: Please post the current code you have for row-major and the code you have already tried for column-major if you want people to help you (and use the tags to format it for proper display). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Background

Row major and column major ordering usually applies when using a 1 dimensional array to represent a two-dimensional array.  Fundamentally, all of memory is a one dimensional array.

### Row Major

The location of an element in a one dimensional array can be found using the equation:

```
location_index = (row_index * columns_per_row) + column_index;
```

### Column Major

Similarly, the location index equation for column major is:

```
location_index = (column_index * rows_per_column) + row_index;
```

### Array View

This means that the 1 dimensional array would be organized like the picture below:

```
Row Major:      R0 C0   R0 C1   R1 C0   R1 C1   ...
              +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
              |       |       |       |       |       |  
              +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
Column Major:   C0 R1   C0 R1   C1 R0   C1 C1
```

Where R# is the row index and C# is the column index.

### Syntax

For row major the array is declared as:

```
Data_Type array[MAXIMUM_ROWS][MAXIMUM_COLUMNS];
```

and column major:

```
Data_Type array[MAXIMUM_COLUMNS][MAXIMUM_ROWS];
```

### Storing Data:

For row-major:

```
array[row][column] = value;
```

For column-major:

```
array[column][row] = value;
```